# Sending data from server

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming

I tried to send data to client using this function

```
protected void SendData(Socket so, string sendData)
{
    byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sendData);
    so.Send(data);

    Console.WriteLine("Sending data back to Client\n");
}
```

I call this function on this function

```
protected void ProcessData(int x, string data, Socket so)
{
    if (x < mybuffersize)
    {
        data = data.Trim();
        SendData(so, data);
    }
}
```

its work well.. and send the data that server received from client.
but when I changed it to this,

```
protected void ProcessData(int x, string data, Socket so)
{
    if (x < mybuffersize)
    {
        data = data.Trim();
        SendData(so, data);
        string sendData = "Testing send string";
        SendData(so, sendData);
    }
}
```

Client will only receive the data he send to me, but not the string `Testing send string`.
Am I doing something wrongly or are there any restriction?

Comment: Are you getting any exception in server send block?

Comment: Where is your client's code? How does it *receive*?

Comment: did you create a code for handling clients receive?

Comment: Am I getting this right? You can send the data as long as you use the `ProcessData` method, but fail if you try to call `SendData` directly?

Comment: @I4V hm... i code it with my friend and he handle the client, but does it really have to do with it, while my first code work?
@RameshDurai nope, its still write `Sending data back to Client` but client never receive anything, but the first part does arrive at client.

Comment: I edited my question. check it again.. @HjalmarZ 
in client side? yes I have, if not the first part couldn't arrive at client wouldn't it? saeed

Comment: What string does the `data` variable hold after `.trim()`?

Comment: @HjalmarZ `.trim()` is just to clear any unused space on `data` so its still the same.

Comment: I know, it might help to see the string that works though. Where do you set the value for the string `data` and what value do you give it? As a side note; I noticed you have one byte array and one string both named `data`. Maybe give them different names to improve readability?

Comment: OK i think i found my solution. i will write it down as my answer... thanks everyone... sorry for not pointing my client is what... i forget about it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem is with sending the data,

it seems my client(flash) will receive the string if i add something like this:

```
protected void ProcessData(int x, string data, Socket so)
{
    if (x < mybuffersize)
    {
        data = data.Trim();
        SendData(so, data);
        string sendData = "Testing send string\0";
        SendData(so, sendData);
    }
}
```

if anyone can explain why, please add at the comment of this answer, thx

Answer (score 1):

We can use TCP messages to send data to client using asynchronous communication.

## Initialize Server Socket and try to connect:

```
// Specify the size according to your need.
private byte[] bytData = new byte[1024 * 50000];
private Socket oServerSocket;

private void WindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // We are using TCP sockets
        this.oServerSocket = new Socket(
        addressFamily: AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
        socketType: SocketType.Stream,
        protocolType: ProtocolType.Tcp);

        // Assign the any IP of the hardware and listen on port number which the hardware is sending(here it's 5656)
        var oIPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(address: IPAddress.Any, port: 5656);

        // Bind and listen on the given address
        this.oServerSocket.Bind(localEP: oIPEndPoint);
        this.oServerSocket.Listen(backlog: 4);

        // Accept the incoming clients
        this.oServerSocket.BeginAccept(this.OnAccept, null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle Exception
    }
}
```

## On Successful connection:

```
private void OnAccept(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        var oClientSocket = this.oServerSocket.EndAccept(asyncResult: ar);

        // Start listening for more clients
        this.oServerSocket.BeginAccept(callback: this.OnAccept, state: null);

        // Once the client connects then start receiving the commands from her
        oClientSocket.BeginReceive(
        buffer: this.bytData,
        offset: 0,
        size: this.bytData.Length,
        socketFlags: SocketFlags.None,
        callback: this.OnReceive,
        state: oClientSocket);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle Exception
    }
}
```

## Process the message received:

```
private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        var oClientSocket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        oClientSocket.EndReceive(asyncResult: ar);

        /* Process the data here

        BitConverter.ToInt32(value: this.bytData, startIndex: 0);
        string SomeString= Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes: this.bytData, index: 8, count: 5);

        */

        // Specify the size according to your need.
        this.bytData = null;
        this.bytData = new byte[1024 * 50000];
        oClientSocket.BeginReceive(
            buffer: this.bytData,
            offset: 0,
            size: this.bytData.Length,
            socketFlags: SocketFlags.None,
            callback: this.OnReceive,
            state: oClientSocket);
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle Exception
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to show me here? creating a server?
did you get what I ask? or my question is not clear?

Comment: The code above shows how to send some message from server to client.

Comment: I know how to... but what i want to ask is, by doing the same thing to different data, it appear my data not received correctly... check my question... still thanks for reply...

Answer (score 0):

Because we don't know what the server does nor how it gets the data, can you please try this and see what the server gets:

```
protected void ProcessData(int x, string data, Socket so)   
{
    if (x < mybuffersize)
    {
        string sendData = "Testing send string\0";
        SendData(so, sendData);
        data = data.Trim();
        SendData(so, data);
    } 
}
```

Comment: well, actually I already got the answer... by just added `\0` on the end of the string... the client can now accept my data... so thanks...